# $S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1} (2n+1) } {n(n+1)} = ?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1} (2n+1) } {n(n+1)} = ?$

**Attempt**: $S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1} (2n) } {n(n+1)} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n(n+1)}  $

$= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty [ \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1} } { (n+1)}] + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n(n+1)}  $

I am stuck on how to move ahead. Please guide me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the first series differentiate the geometric series and for the second try telescoping sum techniques.

Comment: I mean integrate the geometric series.

Comment: But, wouldn't the geometric series will be valid only when $|n|<1$ Could you please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$S_{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right]$$

$$=\left[\log2+(1-\log2)\right]=1$$

> **Otherwise:** $$S_{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+1}$$
>
> $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}+\left[1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\right]=1.$$

As, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent by Leibnitz's test so this series cancel out.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to proceed from here? I am not able to see any telescoping techniques from here though

Comment: different into two sums & then use the expansion of $\log(1+x)$

Comment: Ohhh !! yeaah!!

Comment: @Wanderer no need the series just telescopes.

Comment: @sciona i am trying to telescope. But, for telescoping, you need a minus sign between $1/n$ and $1/(n+1)$. Could you please show me?

Comment: @sciona got it. Thank you!